# Distinct in SQL Server acting weird

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have this table with following data and I need it in certain format

```
Number  | CustName  | Name  |  QtyCust  | QtyMly
--------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------------    
1       |           | AA    | 5067      |  56
2       |           | BB    |  567      | 455
3       |           | CC    |   12      | 244
4       |           | DD    |   43      |  86
4       | AOAO      | DD    |   45      | 437
5       |           | EE    |  655      | 417
5       | BOBO      | EE    |   45      | 397
6       |           | FF    |  345      | 233
6       | COCO      | FF    |  877      |  43
7       |           | GG    |   67      |  87
8       |           | HH    |  469      |  98
```

I need to run distinct or something that the table will be like this:

```
Number  | CustName  | Name  | QtyCust  | QtyMly
--------+-----------+-------+----------+------------
  1     |           | AA    | 5067     |  56
  2     |           | BB    |  567     | 455
  3     |           | CC    |   12     | 244
  4     | AOAO      | DD    |   45     | 437
  5     | BOBO      | EE    |   45     | 397
  6     | COCO      | FF    |  877     |  43
  7     |           | GG    |   67     |  87
  8     |           | HH    |  469     |  98
```

I try to use distinct - but it doesn't work, I got same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using `Distinct`, it will apply on all the columns not just one column. You need `Row_Number` window function to do this

```
select * from 
(
select row_number()over(partition by Name order by  case when CustName <> '' then 1 else 2 end) as rn,*
From yourtable 
) a
Where Rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i need to see the CustName, and on this query i dont see it.